# .NET Core 2.0 dual authentication (Mixing MVC and API)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, authentication

I am a back-end developer who typically develops APIs and and administration panels all under the same project. I primary use Laravel/PHP, however I recently started delving into .NET Core.

In PHP (Laravel), I could tie my API endpoints and webpages to the same controller actions. For example, An API consumer should be able to create a blog post using the API endpoint. Also, the administrator should be able to create a blog post using the web UI, which should follow the same validation logic, etc.

Here is some pseudocode for the `create` action.

```
class BlogPostController
{

    //Create a new blog post
    function create(request)
    {
        authorizeAction(); //Make sure the current user is authorized to create a blog post
        validateFields(request); //Make sure the posted data is valid for a blog post

        //Create the blog post
        blogPost = new BlogPost(request);

        if(request.isAPI)
            return json(blogPost); //Return the new blog post as a json string
        return view(blogPost); //Return an HTML representation of the blog post (in administration panel)
    }


}
```

In Laravel, since all routes can have different middleware, I could define two routes to the above action eg `POST` `/api/blogpost` and `POST` `/blogpost`, each with different authentication schemes. (api would authorize via a JWT token, and the web url would auth via a cookie).

I'm having trouble doing something similar in .NET Core since different authentication schemes cannot be applied via separate middleware [as of Version 2](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310) (as far as I know).

My solution to this problem would be adding two authentication schemes like so:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                })
                .AddCookie(cfg=>cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    cfg.SaveToken = true;
                    cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtKey"])),

                        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                    };
                });
```

And then on my controller use:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

This would effectively challenge a JWT token and a cookie and use whichever one it found. This seems a bit messy to me (and a [Microsoft employee would agree](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1359#issuecomment-324768631))

Am I approaching this whole problem wrong? To me it makes sense to keep all of the logic in one controller and just return json or HTML depending on the type of request. I could have a separate controller for the API endpoints and the webpages, but it seems like a lot of duplication of code. The other option would be to ditch the idea completely and just build an API/Single Page Application that consumes the API.

Is this simply bad design, or is there any elegant way of using different authentication schemes based on the route?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @JeppeRask The closest solution I found was to have two separate controllers. On your MVC controller you can specify [Authorize] to use a cookie by default, and on the API controller you can use [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]  to use the API JWT token.